# FCM push doesn't include my image in case of the recipient time zone from Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I am sending push messages from Firebase console.

I add a image link like below. I am sure he image link is valid.
[image: 1 Notification]

I make a schedule with "Recipient time zone" like below.
[image: 3 Scheduling]

Problem is:

- When I use "Recipient time zone", push messages don't include the image very often.
- When I use a specific time zone like "(GMT-03:00) Sao Paulo Time", push messages do  include the image very often.

I made and tested many options tested to find a suspect.

- Image link does not matter
- Client(Android/iOS) does not matter
- The amount of push doest not matter
- Only time zone is the problem.

Someone can help me?